# Javascript wont run correctly

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/NCt4D/

I want it to move (the image is large), but it dont work.

Firebug says reference scrollDivDown is not defined, but it's there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/NCt4D/1/

`scrollDivDown` was inside a closure and therefore was not accessible in the global scope where the timeout was executing in.

Answer (score 4):

[It's JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NCt4D/5/).

Under "Choose framework", select "no wrap (body)". This prints your code at the end of your content and not wrapped in a function. This is what you would normally/ideally do to a script, which is load them after content, but before the body closes.

and like what the @jcomeau_ictx said, event handlers don't need the `()`. they just require the name (technically, the reference of) the function you want to execute. additionally, if you want to execute more functions on load, than just `scrollDivDown`, you can do:

```
window.onload = function(){
    scrollDivDown();
    foo();
    bar();
    baz();
}
```

also, prepend the subject of your handler (in this case, `window`) before the `onload`. although the subject is implied as `window` in the global scope, just prepend it to avoid confusion. It's also best practice to do so as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload = scrollDivDown;  // do not append ()
```